# GUI problems in Ubuntu 11.04 using 'Ubuntu Classic (No Effects)'

Tags: 11.04, intel-graphics, gui

I have seen some questions like this but I thought I might be able to provide more detail.

I recently installed Ubuntu 11.04 and wiped 10.10. Since my old built-in graphics card is incapable of 3D acceleration, I tried using Ubuntu Classic. After logging in, I was greeted by a choppy background and flickering menus. (I have NEVER had this problem in Ubuntu 10.10). So I even tried logging in using Ubuntu Classic (No effects), the screen was much better this time, but the panels were a little messed up and it crashed on me several times after a few minutes.

I have a Pentium 4 2.66 GHz. 1.5GB RAM. Built in graphics Intel Extreme Graphics 2 96MB memory (I think it's shared not built in memory).

Is it a problem with my graphics card or driver?

Please help.

Comment: if it didn't happened in 10.10 i think it's something with the intel driver loaded in 11.04 that causing the issue, due to ..im guessing..the new Xorg that comes in 11.04 not being compatible with the intel driver, an also adding to that the driver not supporting your IGP.

Answer (score 1):

since ubuntu 10.10 was working well on your machine
then i think it is a bug in the new 11.04 you should report this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

It's listed in Launchpad Bugs
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/727594
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/774999

Two solutions I have found (but not test);

1) Run:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa && sudo apt-get update
&& sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Then reboot the PC and retest.

2) See this:
http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/linux-distributions/linux-distributions4-ubuntu/1540-top-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-1104-natty-narwhal

Comment: Thanx for the fix.